# Print function attribute

Tags: python, string, function, attributes, concatenation

In one module, I am trying to gather raw_inputs and join each, with a space. 
Then, I want to print out the result of a single raw_input:

```
def human_infoz():

    name = raw_input("Enter human name> ")
    address = raw_input("Human Address> ")
    phone = raw_input("Human Phone Number> ")
    email = raw_input("Human Email> ")
    listinfo = ["", name, address, phone, email, ""]
    return ' '.join(listinfo)

go = human_infoz()
print go.name
```

raw_inputs work nice, but when the script reaches namez, it farts.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it is not an attribute, you are running a function, if you want to see the name put  a print statement in your code or make it a class with name as an attribute

Comment: @padraicCunningham added the print statement, still bugging

Comment: I will add an answer, I did not mean that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either put a `print name`  in your code, make a `class` where `name` is an `attribute` or just return name also the assign name to the second arg as below:

```
def human_infoz():

    name = raw_input("Enter human name> ")
    address = raw_input("Human Address> ")
    phone = raw_input("Human Phone Number> ")
    email = raw_input("Human Email> ")
    listinfo = ["", name, address, phone, email, ""]
    return ' '.join(listinfo),name

go = human_infoz()
namez = go[1]
print namez
```

If you want all the details just return the list:

```
def human_infoz():

    name = raw_input("Enter human name> ")
    address = raw_input("Human Address> ")
    phone = raw_input("Human Phone Number> ")
    email = raw_input("Human Email> ")
    listinfo = [name, address, phone, email]
    return listinfo

go = human_infoz()
namez,add,phone,email = go
```

Print all the details:

```
print namez,add,phone,email
```

To access like you are trying in your question you would need  a `class`

This is a very basic example:

```
class Details():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = raw_input("Enter human name> ")
        self.address = raw_input("Human Address> ")
        self.phone = raw_input("Human Phone Number> ")
        self.email = raw_input("Human Email> ")
        self.info = [self.name, self.address, self.phone, self.email]

go = Details() # create instance
# print details by accessing the instance attributes
print go.name,go.address,go.email,go.phone,go.info
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access these variables by name, why not use a dictionary?

```
def human_infoz():

    name = raw_input("Enter human name> ")
    address = raw_input("Human Address> ")
    phone = raw_input("Human Phone Number> ")
    email = raw_input("Human Email> ")
    listinfo = {
        "name": name,
        "address": address,
        "phone": phone,
        "email": email
    }
    return listinfo

go = human_infoz()
print go["name"]
```